Is my proof correct: Showing that $E \cup F$ is Jordan measurable
I'm trying to show that if sets $E,F \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ are Jordan Measurable, then $E \cup F$ is also Jordan measurable.
I think I could use an inner and an outer sets of $E \cup F$ and show that the measure of both would be equal but I also tried an alternative path and I was wondering if it would be correct or not:
$E,F \subset \mathbb{R}^d $ are measurable sets,
there exists $A,B,C,D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$A \subset E \subset B$ and $C \subset F \subset D$
For all $\epsilon > 0$,
$$|\inf m(B) - \sup m(A)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$
idem for $C,F,D$:
$$|\inf m(D) - \sup m(C)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$
by adding these two inequalities, we obtain
$$| \inf m(B) - \sup m(A)| + | \inf m(D) - \sup m(C)| <\epsilon$$
using triangle inequality,
$$| - \sup  m(A)+ \inf m(B) - \sup m(C)+ \inf m(D)| \leq | \inf m(B) - \sup m(A)| + | \inf m(D) - \sup m(C)| < \epsilon $$
by subadditivity,
$$ | - \sup m(C \cup A) + \inf m(B \cup D) +| \leq - \sup m(A)+ \inf m(B) - \sup m(C) + \inf m(D)|  <  \epsilon $$
Therefore:
$$ | \sup m(A \cup C) - \inf m(B \cup D) | < \epsilon $$
so $E \cup F$ is Jordan measurable
Is my reasoning correct and is there anything I could improve? I'm not really sure about using $A \subset E \subset B$ and $C \subset F \subset D$ instead of using $A \subset E \cup F \subset B$. I also feel like there is a rigor issue with my passage where I use subadditivity.

Your proof needs some reorganization:

$A,B,C,D$ must be simple sets.
"For all $\epsilon>0$" must be written before "there exists $A,B,C,D$".
All these $\inf$ and $\sup$ make no sense and should be removed.
Most absolute values are useless. For instance, since $A\subseteq B$, $m(B)-m(A)=m(B\setminus A)\ge0$ hence $|m(B)-m(A)|=m(B)-m(A)$.
The line just after "By subadditivity" (which btw contains 2 minor typos) needs an argument. Better replace it with: $(B\cup D)\setminus(A\cup C)\subseteq(B\setminus A)\cup(D\setminus C)$ hence
$$m(B\cup D)-m(A\cup C)\le m(B\setminus A)+m(D\setminus C)=m(B)-m(A)+m(D)-m(C).$$

